# Will oxygen bleach powder damage the varnish on hardwood floor?

Tags: cleaning, hardwood-floor, varnishing

Somebody recommended using oxygen bleach powder (e.g., Vanish) to get rid of stubborn stains on my hardwood floor. I’m a bit wary of this because it is after all a reactive chemical and an abrasive. What’s the chance the varnish won’t be affected by this? Is there any alternative that can be used to safely get rid of a stain? (The big one I’m trying to remove is from a sheepskin rug someone spilled water on and it got a patch of lanolin+old leather gunk stuck on the floor, and resurfacing is out of my budget.)

Hope this is on-topic, but searching for housekeeping advice just tells me to put vinegar and baking soda on everything.

Comment: Usually it is recommended to test a small in a hidden spot, under a chair/throw rug/behind curtains.  Is it a stain left from removing the lanolin/leather or trying to remove the lanolin/leather?  Would try some hot water and the dishwasher detergent that is good for removing oil first.

Comment: Explaining you you have done so far to remove the stuff/stain might help.  Have you removed the lanolin/leather and just have a stain left?  Might be able to refinish just the area of the stain by hand.

Comment: You want some chemical to dissolve or suck up some stains in the hardwood floor, without staining the floor. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When using an "unknown" product or more precisely a product with an 'unknown" effect on a floor treatment, the usual advice or method is to test in an area that cannot be seen.

Or, if you have a spare piece or offcut then that would make the perfect test piece. HOWEVER, wear and time can render the varnish weaker and more susceptible...

Answer (score 0):

The only safe and guarantied way is the old fashion way.

The problem is that any use of chemical cleaning the stains could result in more stains, since after all you use liquids. You expect the chemicals to dissolve/remove the stain without residue. That is very tough to achieve. You could make a test on small hidden spot to find out in your floor will absorb the chemical and leave no residue in the wood. For that you will have to remove the top coat to expose the wood.

I would not risk it, and simply use a small hand held sander with fine sand paper and sand the spot till you see clean wood. Then apply the surface coat.